# fontspec can’t find small caps even though they appear to exist

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, mac

I’m using `fontspec` to load the Baskerville font that comes with macOS (compiling with XeLaTeX, MacTeX version 2020 fully updated), it’s a truetype collection in `/Library/Fonts/Baskerville.ttc`. Everything seems to work fine except for small caps, even though if I inspect the font in Font Book I can see that it has glyphs for small caps.

[Edited in light of Marcel Krüger’s comment]

From the log, it appears that `fontspec` is *not* aware of them:

```
Package fontspec Info: Font family 'Baskerville(0)' created for font
(fontspec)             'Baskerville' with options [Ligatures=TeX].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"Baskerville/AAT:mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"Baskerville/B/AAT:mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"Baskerville/I/AAT:mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"Baskerville/BI/AAT:mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
```

And later in the log file I get the following warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/Baskerville(0)/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/Baskerville(0)/m/n' instead on input line 68.

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Baskerville}

\begin{document}

\textsc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,} consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! The log actually shows that `fontspec` is *not* aware of them: There is no line starting with `<->` after the scall caps lines. I don't have macOS, but most likely it is a Apply AAT fonts. In contrast to OpenType fonts, these fonts often don't use standardised names for features like small caps, so how to enable them can only be answered by someone who has access to the actual font.

Comment: Ah, thank you @MarcelKrüger, I was unaware of the significance of `<->` in the log. It _may_ be an Apple AAT font. Unfortunately inspecting the font in Font Book doesn’t say.

Comment: The font has no feature available (or obtainable from XeTeX). The free BaskervilleF font available in TeX Live has small caps.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, unfortunately BaskervilleF is, in my subjective opinion, not as pretty as the Monotype version that ships with macOS. As the macOS Baskerville does contain glyphs for small caps I’m hoping that there might be some hackery to tell `fontspec` how to find them.

Comment: @ddbrierton Possibly dismembering the `.ttc` into a bunch of `.otf` files might do the trick.

Comment: @ddbrierton No, even splitting the `.ttc` file into individual `.ttf` files doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for trying @egreg.

Comment: It's possible to use the small caps from BaskervilleF, though. I think it's possible, with LuaLaTeX, to add a feature to a font, maybe somebody can help, maybe @MarcelKrüger

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at this on my old iMac and it appears that this particular font (on my High Sierra machine it is Monotype Baskerville v13.0) has a problem with the encoding of the small caps. They are available inside the font for A-Z and also for the Deseret-alphabet (but not for combining marks or interpunction). But I can't access them even in InDesign. Actually, InDesign does show small caps but they appear to be faked ones, i.e. scaled upper case letters which have the wrong weight (too thin). When I inspect the font with a font editor, it shows nothing at all in the `features` tab.

As a test, I opened the `.ttf` with the font editor Glyphs2, renamed the small caps from `.small` to `.sc`, updated the `smcp` feature, renamed the font to "BaskervilleSC" and exported as an `.otf`. I installed the resulting `.otf` file on my system and when compiling a test file with `xelatex` it produces the correct small caps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{BaskervilleSC}

\begin{document}

Barry

\textsc{Barry}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So, to solve your problem you could either

- try to find a newer/different version of Baskerville that does not have this issue or
- try modifying the font at hand in the manner that I described (I am not sure whether this is allowed by the license).